# Copy permissions over to production database in django

Tags: django-models, django-permissions

My current development database is SQLITE3 that comes packaged with Django. I have set up a MySql database as production database. The migrations went through smoothly and all the tables are now set up correctly.
We have two sets of users with their own permissions. First is the web customers who by stuff from us, return stuff, post reviews etc. The second is the store employees/managers who set up the inventories, add/remove items from the store etc. Is there a way I can migrate these permissions from SQLITE to MySQL without doing it manually one permission at a time?